# How to use GPG with Gmail?

Tags: gmail, privacy, google-chrome

I would like to read and write [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) encrypted mails within Gmail. I found [FireGPG](http://getfiregpg.org/s/home), but the support for Gmail has been discontinued (and I am using Google Chrome as a browser).

What is the most practical way to achieve this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is currently no reasonable way to use GPG/PGP from within Gmail directly.  The only two options are to encrypt the message manually from a client-side tool, pasting the result into Gmail when you're done, or to use a desktop mail client with GPG integration (such as Thunderbird + [Enigmail](http://enigmail.net)) to send messages you need to be encrypted.  Decrypting would likewise entail downloading the message from Google as raw source, running it through the desktop client to decrypt, and reading it there.

Comment: It would be really nice if Google provided a Google Chrome extension for this.

Comment: @Julien you could write one :)

Comment: I wouldn't trust myself enough to use it :)

Comment: What do you think Google would offer in the way of targeted advertising for PGP-encrypted mail content? 

"Tin foil hats, $0.99 each!"

Comment: the whole notion of having a chrome plugin for this is dicey. browsers and the www in general are safe because they're entirely divorced from a machine's local filesystem. there is no way to use a secret key file from within a Chrome plugin without uploading your secret to someone else. which violates the entire concept of GPG encryption. now watch me put an answer down below pointing people to the very Chrome plugin you're asking for.

Comment: It's worse than that. Chrome by it's nature cannot be secured. Says so right in the license that Google intends to spy on and spam you and that you have no choice but to choose another browser. At the very least, I recommend Chromium rather than Chrome.

Comment: Now Gmail encrypts mails using S/MIME algorithm.

Comment: Just a note for people reading this in the future. Thunderbird now supports E2EE natively, therefore you don't need Enigmail anymore. Just set it up `Edit > Acccount Settings > End-To-End Encryption`. Also see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/openpgp-thunderbird-howto-and-faq.

Answer (score 18):

Came across a very promising looking Chrome extension for sending and receiving GPG encrypted emails: [mailvelope](http://www.mailvelope.com/).

It supports a variety of webmail providers.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

There is now an [alpha-quality Chrome extension for using GPG in Gmail](http://blog.thinkst.com/2011/09/chrome-extension-for-gpg-in-gmail.html). I have not tried it, so I cannot vouch for it.

FYI "apps and extentions can not be added from this website"
http://thinkst.com/tools/cr-gpg/

Comment: Doesn't work on win64 right now.

Comment: The gpg chrome plugin was having issues on Win64, but these should be resolved now. Please drop me a note if its still not working for you.
([http://thinkst.com/tools/cr-gpg](http://thinkst.com/tools/cr-gpg))

Comment: It's now 2021 (stay in 2011, if you can!) and it's still in Alpha.

Answer (score 8):

The best Google Chrome extension for this is: ["Mymail-Crypt For Gmail"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mymail-crypt-for-gmail/jcaobjhdnlpmopmjhijplpjhlplfkhba)

The Decrypt and Encrypt buttons are well located and easy to use:

### [image: Decrypt button]

such as the managing interface, plus doesn't require you to have **gpg** installed in your computer.

Answer (score 5):

Google has a plugin for Chrome called [End to End](https://code.google.com/p/end-to-end/) which will allow exactly that.  However, it's currently in alpha, and has to be compiled yourself.  There's no word on if it will ever be an official part of chrome.

It supports Elliptic Curve Cryptography as part of OpenPGP ([RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) — OpenPGP Message Format, and [RFC 6637](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6637) — Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) in OpenPGP ), and operates in JavaScript inside of Chrome, utilizing [local storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#Local_and_session_storage) for key storage.  The key database is encrypted when Chrome is not running, and sandboxed when Chrome is running, so it should be relatively secure.

Comment: Now in 2018, this extension seems to be abandoned.

Comment: @ElliotSchep yes, it seems so.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows I just encrypt in [VisualGPG](http://notepad.patheticcockroach.com/2351/visualgpg-a-simple-gui-for-gnupg/) and then copy/paste into Gmail (plaintext e-mail, of course). Not that convenient, but no too much of a hassle either, considering how often I actually use GnuPG.

Edit: and on Mac, [GPGTools](http://www.gpgtools.org/projects.html) seems quite comprehensive.

Comment: The "plaintext" approach no longer works with gmail, unfortunately, due to formatting decisions made by google. See here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/gmail-plain-text

Answer (score 2):

I came across [GPG4browsers](http://gpg4browsers.recurity.com/). It's possible to check a signed messages and I can import my private keys. Apart from that it's still in an early stage.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply mail through IMAP, and use your favourite desktop mail client? It's practical, but not a webapp however...

Answer (score 0):

Gmail with `gpg4win` won't work, with clients like `claws mail`, because every key stroke is sent to the server unencrypted.

Solution:

`pgp4win + gnupgnotepad + copypaste encrypted message to gmail`. webclients have inherent security issues, better don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

[FlowCrypt](https://flowcrypt.com/) is another browser extension.

While Mailvelope can work with system GnuPG installation optionally, I think FLowCrypt cannot. Mailvelope also requires a license if you want to use with a corporate account (or you must rebuild it yourself).

I'm not sure about any other advantages or disadvantages it may have. Authors claim Flowcrypt's code is cleaner. But because of the system GnuPG integration, I decided to use Mailvelope at the end.

Comment: from what I can see, FlowCrypt is using `OpenPGP` and helping the user attach pgp-encrypted files/messages. + existing gmail infrastructure (to send the encrypted message as an attachment).  And reversing the process on recipient end.  Vs having to manually copy files yourself.   When users jump to an entirely different infrastructure (protonmail, Mailvelope, etc), you still must trust the infrastructure is secure/uncompromised in its purpose.

Comment: @JonGrah, I'm currently a mailvelope user. But I prefer things to go through OpenGPG because I use same infra for all use cases. It's better for me to store my key in one place and use for email, git, etc. than having 2 trust stores. So it is subjective and depends on use cases and trust.